# How to create properties of an interface based on another interface dynamically?

Tags: typescript

I want to create an Interface based on another Interface.

Let's say I have a data interface that looks like this:

```
interface SimpleData {
    uid: number;
    name: string;
    email: string;
}
```

And I want to create another interface that represents a validated `SimpleData` object, like this:

```
interface ValidatedSimpleData {
    uid: { value: SimpleData["uid"], error: boolean };
    name: { value: SimpleData["name"], error: boolean };
    email: { value: SimpleData["email"], error: boolean };
}
```

Is there is a way to create the properties of `ValidatedSimpleData` dynamically based on the properties defined in `SimpleData`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this via [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).

> A mapped type is a generic type which uses a union created via a keyof to iterate through the keys of one type to create another:

```
interface SimpleData {
    uid: number;
    name: string;
    email: string;
}

type Validated<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: {
        value: T[K],
        error: boolean
    }
}

type ValidatedSimpleData = Validated<SimpleData>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMrALYAcA2EAicYcyA3gFDJXICuwAJgFzIg0YBG0A3JdSHBgjMAzmCigA5j2rIIGOMBwixkngF9y5MAE8sKAGpwcDIhHoAeACoA%20ZAF4yvKgG0A0slDIA1hG0B7GGRLAF1mChkZADcjGiEgt2CAGicI6Cg-KGZ2Pz88OBAUjQ0tXQMjE0h6dGw8QmJ7ZENjelMLatwCIjhrLiA)

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. 
It is also possible to specify the new properties to be required, through: `K in keyof Required<T>`.  Awesome!